# Is it true is $E(X^2)=1$, then $E(X^4)\geq 1$?

Tags: probability

I suspect it is true and I cannot find any counterexamples, but it doesn't readily follow from Holder's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Jensen's inequality, 
$$
1 = E(X^2) \leq \sqrt{E(X^4)},
$$
which gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

Define $Z=X^2$.  Then 
$$0\leq\operatorname{Var}(Z)=E(Z^2)-(E(Z))^2=E(X^4)-(E(X^2))^2=E(X^4)-1.$$

Answer (score -1):

Expectation operator holds monotonicity i.e if $X\geq Y$ then $E[X] \geq E[Y]$. So if the random variable $X^2 \leq X^4$ then $E[X^2] \leq E[X^4]$, for this the the random variable $X \in [1,\infty]$ otherwise the equality sign would change.

Comment: What you say is true but somewhat useless because $X(\Omega)\subset[1,\infty[$ or $X(\Omega)\subset[0,1]$ implies that $X=1$ a.s. if $\mathbb EX^2=1$.

Comment: You cannot say that convergence in $r^{th}$ moment implies almost sure convergence and vice versa.

Comment: I guess @MaximilianJanisch is saying that in general, if $X \in [a, b]$ and $E(X^r) = a$ for any $r$, then $X = a$ a.s., which is true